# RobotFramework and DB - how to reference a value from a returned record?

Tags: database, robotframework

So I used the following:

```
${versions_record}=  Select From Database
    ...  Select * from versions where item_id = '${item_id}' and item_type = '${item_type}' and whodunnit = 'Web Service Request'
```

This will return my record, but how do I reference a field's value? (E.g., the `item_type` that is in the record.)

Comment: Are you using the Robot Framework Database Library? This is unclear from your question. See:
http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.6/DatabaseLibrary.html

Answer (score 0):

The database query returns a list of tuples - so the value of `${versions_record}` would be (made up example, the actual data depends on the db schema):

```
[(1, 23, 'text'),
 (2, 45, 'another text')]
```

To reference a particular row in the result set, you should use `${versions_record[0]}` where `0` is the record number (the index are 0 based - e.g. the 1st is 0, and so on).
To reference a column value in a record row, use additional index - again, 0 based - so `${versions_record[0][0]}` would get the first column of the first record.

If the query returns only one row, you should use the same syntax anyway (i.e. the returned value is a one-member list).